# Handling configuration changes in OSMDroid + Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, osmdroid, android-darkmode

I'm trying to use OSMDroid library in my Compose Android app. I used [this](https://gist.github.com/ArnyminerZ/418683e3ef43ccf1268f9f62940441b1) approach and it works great, but when I change to dark mode in my app, the map becomes just a grid, and no tiles are displayed. It keeps the same if I revert the dark mode. If I start the app in dark mode it works fine, but when changed to light mode it breaks again. Basically, I can't change the light/dark mode while using the app. Any polygon I draw also disappears and I would like to maintain them in the view.

I've managed ti move the `MapView` declaration to a `ViewModel` and manually call the `onPause()`  and `onReseme()` functions in the activity lifecycle, but I haven't solved the problem.

```
MainViewModel.kt
class MainViewModel(context: MainActivity): ViewModel(){
    var mapView: MapView = MapView(context).apply {
        id = R.id.map
        clipToOutline = true
        tileProvider = MapTileProviderBasic(context, TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK)
        tileProvider.tileRequestCompleteHandlers.add(SimpleInvalidationHandler(this))
        zoomController.setVisibility(CustomZoomButtonsController.Visibility.NEVER)
        setMultiTouchControls(true)
    }
}
```

```
Mainscreen Composable function
@Composable
fun MapScreen(
 mainViewModel: MainViewModel
) {

    MapView(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues),
            mapViewState = mainViewModel.mapView
        )

}
```

```
MapView function (modified from GitHub)
@Composable
fun MapView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    useDarkScheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    mapViewState: MapView = rememberMapViewWithLifecycle(),
    onLoad: ((map: MapView, controller: IMapController) -> Unit)? = null
) {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { mapViewState },
        modifier = modifier
    ) { mapView ->
        val mapController: IMapController = mapView.controller
        onLoad?.invoke(mapView, mapController)
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciatted!